# Regex confusion on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have these kinds of strings in my document

```
<year of publication: 2007>
<कुम्भ-कारस्य>U
```

My aim is to bookmark the first kind of lines from my document.
I use  the following  regex expression `(?<=\<)([a-z]+?)(?<=\>)`
This however ends up selecting the U in the second string too. What can I fix? This is on Notepad++

Comment: Have you had time to check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67241627/3832970) yet?

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, you need to use a positive *lookahead*, not lookbehind, on the right side of your regex pattern:

```regex
(?<=<)([a-z]+?)(?=>)
                ^^^ change is here
```

Note that if you more generally just want to match tag contents, you could use:

```regex
<(.*?)>
```

And then access the first capture group.

Comment: This ignores the alphabets after the angular bracket but it ends us ignoring the other strings too. <year of publication: 2007> this is not matched anymore

Comment: What do you actually want to match here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to the fact that you are using `\<` and `\>`, leading and trailing *word boundaries*, rather than `<` and `>`, *angle bracket patterns*. The `U` letter is matched because

- You have *Match Case* option checked OFF and
- The `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries and `U` is preceded with `>` and not followed with a word char, i.e. it is enclosed with word boundary positions.

If you want to match lines with a pattern like `<[LOWERCASE_WORD](optional lowercase words)?: [DIGITS]>` you can use

```php
(?-i)<[a-z]+(?:\h+[a-z]+)*:\h*\d+>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CXfLWv/1).

*Details*

- `(?-i)` - the pattern is now case sensitive
- `<` - a `<` char
- `[a-z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?:\h+[a-z]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more horizontal whitespace and one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `:` - a colon
- `\h*` - one or more horizontal whitespace
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `>` - a `>` char.

*Bonus*

These are some variations for you in case your pattern does not have to be that strict:

- `<[a-z\h]*:[^<>]*>` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CXfLWv/2)) - matches `<`, then zero or more spaces and letters (respecting your *Match Case* setting), `:`, then any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `>`
- `<[a-z][^>]*>` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CXfLWv/3)) - matches `<`, an ASCII letter (respecting your *Match Case* setting), then any zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a very strict understanding of your question `<` followed by one or more non-brackets up until a `year` followed by a `>`, I would suggest something like:

- [`<[^>]+: \d{4}>`](https://regex101.com/r/LNI0Tc/2)

[image]

For something more complex or a better understanding, check out Wiktor's answer.